# Shuffle probability that it is a unique permutation

Tags: probability

If I shuffle 62 characters and get the first 12 shuffled characters, what is the probability that it is a unique permutation never before configured?

Comment: What do you mean by 'never' before?  how many shuffles of this kind have been done before?

Comment: My mistake. Consider that this kind of shuffle hasn't been done before.

Comment: Your question needs more details. What do you mean "never before configured" or "shuffle hasn't been done before". Does it mean you are doing this twice and you want the probability that in the second time, you are getting something different from the first time?

Comment: @AbhiramNatarajan If I shuffle about 500 times, what is the probability? "Before configured" = not sorted.